# Background size and position alternative for < IE 9

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, internet-explorer

I'm having a question regarding `background` properties on older IEs. I have a dynamic website, where users can create own Pinterest like posts, with images and some text in it. In the past, when it was about to fit an image into a specific height or width (without any sort of image cropping logic) I found something like

```
.image-wrapper {
  background-image: url('some/url.png');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

to be the best way.

But for an upcoming project, I need to guarantee that it works for IE 8 as well and since [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-position) says it doesn't work for it I need some suggestions how to fit an image to a specific height and width without knowing the ratio of the image the user wants to upload.

I prefer a CSS only way, but if thats not satisfying I'm open for JS/jQuery too.

Answer (score 0):

The on your are quoting is `CSS background-position edge offsets`, which is a 3 to 4 items syntax (say you want to do `bottom 4px right 10px` to offset 4 and 10px from the bottom right). IE8 does suppor two-value syntax (aka `center center`, the one you quote). You can see that it has basic support (two value syntax) since version 4: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position#Browser_compatibility

However, you background-size problem is not easily solved. Usually computers using IE8 dont have resolutions larger than 1320x768 so make sure your images are that size. Otherwise you could try adding your image in an image tag as the first element and giving it a min-height and min-width of 100%;

```
<div id="Container">
    <img src="bg.jpg" class="background" />
</div>

#Container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.background {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute; /* need it for z-index and to make sure content overlaps */
    z-index: -1; /* z-index is supported since IE4 */
}
```

#### Update

I added `overflow: hidden; position: relative;` to the `#Container`. Also, if you go down this route a good way to center your image for modern browsers is:

```
.background:nth-child(n){
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Otherwise, use javascript:

```
$(this).resize(function(){
    $(".background").each(function(){
        var w = $(this).innerWidth() / 2;
        var h = $(this).innerHeight() / 2;
        $(this).css({
            "left" : "50%",
            "top" : "50%",
            "margin-left" : -w + "px",
            "margin-top" : -h + "px"
        });
    });
});
$(this).resize();
```

Comment: I thought about using an `<img>` tag instead width `min-height` and `min-width` of 100%. But the problem with that is, it would leave white space depending on the images aspect ratio.

Comment: Thats the thing, if both min- values are set it should scale automatically to be at least covering the screen. The thing is you can't actually center the image with CSS in that case. I've recently used it and it works all the way back to IE7 as far as I can see.

Comment: it would would stretch yes, but it would distort the image, thats something I wouldn't want of course!

Comment: It won't stretch if your width and height are auto. It will have a minimum width of 100%, but not a width of 100%. It would mean that if the width is larger when the height is 100%, then the width _will be larger_. Try it out, it works.

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden; position: relative;` since the position needs to be within the div (so the div needs to have position declared) and we dont want the background outside the div. I'll amend my post to do this as well.

Comment: yeah but it is not centered, it starts  at the left-top. And assuming the `main content` of every image is in the middle, it does not fit what I want to achieve!

Comment: Then use JS, added it to my post. But seriously, after doing all this your main complaint is its not centred? Thats the easy bit if you know basic jQuery...

Comment: okay that seem to work :) was hoping for a CSS only way, but I guess it does what I need!

Comment: If thats the right answer could you mark it as such? Cheers

Comment: I want to give it some more time, since I believe theres probably another solution which I prefer more. But I don't forget to answer if theres nothing else, no worries!